# Is this MySQL query equivalent to this Django query

Tags: python, mysql, django

Is this MySQL Query

```
SELECT * from books WHERE ISBN = (SELECT isbn_id FROM userWishlist WHERE userid_id = request.user.id)
```

equivalent to this Django query?

```
q = userWishlist.objects.filter(userid_id = request.user.id).values('isbn_id')

return books.objects.filter(ISBN = q)
```

edit: Here are the models for userWishList and book

```
class books (models.Model):
    ISBN = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookVersion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookAuthor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookPublisher = models.CharField(max_length=255, default= 'NULL')
class wishlist (models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    ISBN = models.ForeignKey(books, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: This will not work: `q` is a *collection* of `isbn_id`s, not a single one.

Comment: But nevertheless it is inefficient. Can you provide the relevant models (`userwishlist` and `books`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnse  yes i know it's not a single one, but i want it to list out the books that a user wishlisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> equivalent to this Django query?

**No**. Django expects a single value for equivalences, but the `q` object is a *`QuerySet`* of values.

Furthermore it is not necessary to use this. You can filter with:

```
books.objects.filter(wishlist__userid=request.user)
```

This will thus list all `books` for which a `wishlist` exists which has as `userid` the `request.user`.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`wishlist`</s> to `Wishlist`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Book` instead of <s>`books`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).